# How to correctly translate "Upload a track" from English?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I ask my friends to help to translate my web app to Spanish and when work had done I took one translate and put in on google translate.

It is about GPS track (file with points from GPS logger). 
"Upload a track" was translated as "Descargar la pista", but google translated "Descargar" as "download" and I found on one forum that GPS tracking is something like " rastrear/localizar/ubicar"

So, could you please help me with translation of "Upload a track"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is true that not many technical words are translated, I think this is not the case.
In Spanish from Spain, *track* is translated as "**pista**", for audio/video domains but also for other meanings (like *walk on a track*), but as **ruta**, **itinerario** or **trayecto** in the *GPS track* meaning.
So I'd say  **Subir una ruta** or **Cargar una ruta** if, as it looks like by the context, you had to put that text on a button that for example, uploads a GPS track to a map. The other two words (itinerario or trayecto) are still valid and could be also used.

Comment: +1 para ti. En otra respuesta sugerí "rastro" pero es mucho mejor tu "ruta", sin duda. En todo caso, si fuera mi app yo dejaría la palabra "track".

Comment: +1 Nice answer!

Comment: El problema es que si leo *ruta* supongo que refiere a una *route*, que en GPS es algo distinto que un *track*.

Comment: Do you mean with "en GPS es algo distinto que un track" that the question uses "track" as a verb (seguir, rastrear) instead of as a noun (ruta, itinerario)?

Comment: No, *route* and *track* are both nouns that refer to different things in GPS vocabulary. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_navigation_software

Comment: Ok. However, the RAE says that "ruta" means, among other things, "camino o dirección que se toma para un propósito", or "Itinerario para el [viaje]", which would be quite precisely a route. Anyway, I'm far to be an expert in GPS terminology.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, that *ruta* can be the translation of *route*, but you are proposing it as a translation of *track*.

Answer (score 2):

Generally technical words are not translated. I would use

> cargar un track

In GPS terminology the meaning of "track" is very different from the current. Maybe you prefer its synonym "trace". That way you could use

> cargar un rastro
>
> cargar una huella

And finally I do not know if it would be far from the meaning, but you can use

> rastrear

Comment: Whether people do or do not make a careful distinction between *cargar* and *descargar* depends mostly on the habits of the speaker.  As in English, with the distinction between *download* and *upload*.  Some people "download" photos from their phone to their gallery, while others "upload" them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are easy and intuitive solutions for this translation. `Cargar` might be the direct oposite of `descargar`. To me it also might have some connotations, like if you were preparing something to be played.

Sometimes *download* is translated as `bajar`, as opposed to `descargar`.

> Te **bajas** la JDK de la página oficial de Oracle y te la instalas donde quieras.

So one option could be trying with `subir` for upload, as the opposite term.

> Subir track

**One note:** my Dropbox account, for example, on its web version  uses `cargar` (actually "*cargando...*") when is uploading the data to be shown (UI components and interface) and uses the term `subir` for me to upload content to the site.

I think that you could also use `importar` as instead of *uploading* it you were *importing* it to the cloud. The problem is that export and import usually have different connotation in these kind of applications.